# Does c# allow skipping reference to a static class only for extension methods?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This shows http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311042.aspx that a reference to a public static extension class in a public static namespace can be skipped.
However, it doesn't work with public static variables.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
namespace NDefault
{
    public static class TDefault
    {
        public static int CNT=71;
        public static bool has_method(this object target,string method_name)
        {
            return target.GetType().GetMethod(method_name)!=null;
        }
    }
}
```

_

```
  using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using NDefault;

public class TController :MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start () 
    {
        int t;
        print (t.has_method("GetType")); //This prints "True"
        print (CNT);//This creates error "The name `CNT' does not exist in the current context"

    }
    void Update () 
    {

    }
}
```

Am I right, that for using static variables and methods without a class reference, I have to inherit all classes from a non-static default class containing  them, while for extension methods I should create a separate static class in a namespace? I.e. I can't store them together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have extension methods and regular static methods/properties in the same static class. For clarity it is best to separate them.

When accessing static properties/methods you must specify the class they belong to. So to access the CNT static property it would be

```
int cnt = TDefault.CNT;
```

in your case it would then be

```
print (TDefault.CNT);
```

This rule applies for extension methods as well. For extension methods, you must have a using statement for the namespace the extension method is defined in. You must also specify the object that the extension method is for. In your example, your extension methods works for all classes. This usually is not advised unless you are adding value to all classes. you usually want to specify a particular class

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool NewMethod(this MyObject source)
    {
        return true;
    {
}
```

The method above will only be available on the MyObject class, and not other classes. Unlike "normal" static methods, extension methods require an instance of an object in order to work as "extension methods". Both samples below will work.

```
MyObject o = new MyObject();
bool val = o.NewMethod();

// this also will get the value
val = Extensions.NewMethod(o);
```